# How to add one more condition in this if block?

Tags: javascript

How to add one more condition in this if block ??

I want to run in the if block only if the quantity_traded value is greater than 800 and also less than 20000

This is my code

```
var difference  = -3000;

var quantity_traded = 800 ;

var stockprice = 300;

if (difference >= -4000 && quantity_traded >= 800 && stockprice>=300)
{
    alert('include');
}

else
{
    alert('dont include');
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2ok0fcax/

Could you please let me know how to match the quantity_traded value is greater than 800 and also less than 20000 condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add `quantity_traded < 20000` to your list of conditions

```
if (difference >= -4000 && quantity_traded >= 800 && stockprice>=300 quantity_traded < 20000) {
  ...
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2ok0fcax/1/

Comment: i am sorry for this question .